# Matching Chosen Options to Correct Answers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of correct answers in Col G for four questions, located in cells G3:G6. In Col B (Options), there are questions and answer options – starting with question 1 in cell B2 and its answer options in B3, B4, B5, and B6. This pattern continues with question 2 in cell B7 and its options in the following cells.
In Col C (Response), the chosen options, is depicted with '1' and '0' for unselected ones. I need an Excel formula to check if the chosen option matches with the correct answers in Column G. If the response is correct, I want it to be marked as 'Yes,' otherwise, mark it as 'No'.

Here is the formula I worte
`=IF(AND(B3<>"", INDEX(G$3:G$6, MATCH(B3, $B3:$B6, 0)) = C3), "Yes", "No")`

however I'm not getting the desired result.. for Illustrative purposes I've created a possible result column and highlighted "Yes" in red. But I'm getting "No". Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Try this formula instead: `=IF(C3=1,IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B3,$G$3:$G$5,0))),"Yes","No"),"no")`. (and yes, I deliberately spelled "No" and "no" so that to start with you understand which logical path was taken. You can change it when you're ready)

Comment: Thanks @PeterT.This is working, however could you please explain why you have not included cell G6 in range $G$3:$G$5. And can't seem to get around the logic of  "No" and "no". Again your help is appreciated here.

Comment: The formula **should** include G6, as in `$G$3:$G$6`. My mistake. Don't worry about the "No", "no" - just make both of those "No" and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT. It is working. One query though if I want to calculate % of correct response "Yes" . In our scenario its only 1 yes so its 25% or 1/4 however if I drag the formula the "No" would also be populated infront of question also C7, C12, C17. How can I get this percentage? Any idea /tboughts

Comment: **Assuming that there will only be a single "1" for each group of options**, you can use the formula `=COUNTIF(E:E,"Yes")/COUNTIF(C:C,1)`. This counts the number of correct answers (the number of "Yes" in column E) by the number of questions (i.e. the number of 1's in column C).

Comment: Great @PeterT. It worked.. Do you have any freelancing portfolio, I could recommend you if I came across some jobs

Comment: I don't have a portfolio, just my profile here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in column F

```
=IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(B3,G$3:G$6,0)>0,FALSE),C3=1),"YES","NO")
```

and conditional formatting

Highlight Cell Rules -> Equal to ... -> type YES and select Red Text press OK

Comment: Thanks for taking out the time to answer the question, however, this solution is not working for me. Much appreciated

Comment: Did you drag it down?

Comment: @D Alam Would you please tell what was the concrete result of using this formula? This would be a help for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the formula in cell `D2`

```
=IF(C2="","",IF((C2=1)*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2,$G$3:$G$6))),"Yes","No"))
```

---

Assuming you have a current version of office with lambda function you could give a try

```
=MAP(C2:C21,B2:B21,LAMBDA(ss,bd,IF(ss="","",IF((ss=1)*(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(bd,$G$3:$G$6))),"Yes","No"))))
```

Comment: I don't have a current version of office so I can't test the lambda function. Your help is appreciated though.

Comment: Posted both variants.  From the image you have posted thought might be using office 365.  Anyways thank you for taking time to post a question